# How can I randomly select n rows per group a different number of times for each group in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, loops, random

I basically have two tables, both of which contain two columns - a list of people ID and their birth year, like this:

```
ID   birth_year 
1      1981
2      1982
3      1982
4      1983
etc
```

For each person in table 1 I need to select 6 people at random with the same birth year from table 2.

I think I can use `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT 6` in this query. My issue is that in table 1 there are many with the same birth year, maybe 102 people born in 1987 and 88 people born in 1988. How can I write the query such that it selects 6 random people born in 1987 102 times, and 88 times for 1988?

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to learn and begin to understand this OVER/Partition concept some and think its what you are looking for.

My understanding of the "OVER" clause states... Of the records you are querying, I want you to break them into groups based on whatever the declared "PARTITION" component is defined.  So, with your request, you want to group each by their respective year.

Now, the ORDER BY within the partition call is where you would apply your RAND().  So, within each PARTITION (the birth year), order those records by the RAND().

So now, we can grab the built-in function ROW_NUMBER() to get the records as they are returned and sorted in the group 1, 2, 3, etc...

By making this an inner pre-query, you can now filter down where the final row is <= 6, so you get 6 from each birth year group.

```
select 
      pq.*
   from
      ( select 
              id,  
              birth_year, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY birth_year order by rand()) finalRow
           from 
              YourTable
           order by 
              birth_year ) pq
   where 
      pq.finalRow <= 6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would this query give me six random rows for each birth year? Because I would need 6*n random rows, since the number of people with the same birth year from table 1 varies. So I think I would need a kind of loop query where it "scans" table 1 and for each row in table 1, selects 6 random rows with the same birth year from table 2. Maybe I can integrate the query you wrote with such a loop query?

Comment: @millamagia, run the query... It will give 6 random entries PER birth year.  No looping required.  That is what the "OVER( PARTITION )" is for.  Its almost like doing a select top 6 for 1979 UNION select top 6 for 1980 UNION select top 6 for 1981...

Comment: Yes, but I need 6 random entries per person in Table 1, not per birth year. Table 1 consists of 5000 people with in total 123 different birth years, and for each person I need to randomly select 6 people from Table 2 with the same birth year. My result table should therefore be approximately 30 000 people. But I tried your query and wrote SELECT table2.ID, table2.birth_year, ROW_NUMBER PARTITION BY table1.ID table1.birth_year ORDER BY RAND(), which gives the right number of rows, but the randomization seems really off.. The same person was selected too many times for it to be random.

Comment: @millamagia, then please edit your ORIGINAL post.  Put the sample structure of BOTH tables and show some sample records (simple row-entries using spaces for alignment) and show about 10-15 rows and then show sample of what you EXPECT to get ( obviously lower count per the sample data size, but enough to show the context).  You never indicated a second table to go against.