# multiple LEFT JOIN using LIMIT on one of the joins

Tags: mysql

I looked around for answers to this question but all the ones I tried simply didn't work. The other answer suggestions all threw errors for me. Maybe it's because I'm using using MariaDB ?.

```
SELECT * FROM 'view_winners'
```

I need top 3 in column 'class'

table view_winners is multiple left joins and I could not figure out how to limit 3 of the left join on table allClasses.

view_winners is:

```
`$view = "view_winners";
  $db->query("DROP $view");
  $db->query("CREATE VIEW $view AS
    SELECT *
    FROM thw22 evnt
      LEFT JOIN allUsers usr
        ON usr.user_id = evnt.e_owner_id
      LEFT JOIN hw_vehicles veh
        ON veh.vehicle_id = evnt.e_vehicle_id
      LEFT JOIN hw_m_vehicle_class mcls
        ON mcls.v_class_id = evnt.e_class_id
      LEFT JOIN allClasses cls
        ON mcls.cvm_id = cls.class_id
      LEFT JOIN hw_v_scores sco
        ON sco.v_score_id = evnt.e_score_id
    WHERE (cls.class_name <> '' OR cls.class_name IS NOT NULL)
      AND (sco.total <> '' OR sco.total IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY cls.vehicle_type ASC, cls.class_name ASC, sco.total DESC
  ");`
```

It's probably best if I could LIMIT 3 on LEFT JOIN allClasses but I can't figure that out. So I figured I would loop through the result and unset rows over 3 in class in PHP. But again I could not figure out how to compare rows as looping through.

I need help with the LIMIT 3 on the JOIN or how to compare the results unsetting rows.

| entry | class | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 786 | sally | 99 |
| 234 | sally | 90 |
| 456 | bob | 45 |
| 621 | joe | 90 |
| 964 | joe | 80 |
| 548 | joe | 66 |
| 346 | joe | 22 |
| 900 | frank | 89 |
| 700 | frank | 86 |
| 800 | frank | 72 |
| 123 | frank | 70 |
| 860 | frank | 50 |
| 333 | frank | 45 |

Desired results:

| entry | class | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 786 | sally | 99 |
| 234 | sally | 90 |
| 456 | bob | 45 |
| 621 | joe | 90 |
| 964 | joe | 80 |
| 548 | joe | 66 |
| 900 | frank | 89 |
| 700 | frank | 86 |
| 800 | frank | 72 |

Comment: While I'm absolutely sure there is a good answer to this question, I'm also sure that I'm not going to be able to figure it out without knowing the schema and sample contents of all the tables being joined. Ideally you would include a `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table, and `INSERT`s for the contents, so people can run them and be ready to go trying different solutions.

Comment: ok. I didn't think that far ahead. They relational DB is (for me) too complicated. My last working DB was just a flat table. It was much easier. I can't do this tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having so many joins and confusing myself badly, I made a couple different views that I will need anyway for other statistics. Then by simply ordering by class ASC, score DESC I have a very simple master list of all classes in order then scores highest to lowest (along with all the other joined data). After that I can compare each row and limit 3 as follows:

```
            SELECT * FROM
              (SELECT *,
                @rn := IF(@prev = class_name,
                @rn + 1, 1)
               AS rn,
                @prev := class_name
               FROM view_allScores
               JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0)
                 AS vars
              ) AS T1
            WHERE T1.rn <= 3
```

The confusing thing was that I was trying to add a LIMIT to a join and that kept confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

[Might this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802140/how-can-i-randomly-select-n-rows-per-group-a-different-number-of-times-for-each/64809418#64809418)

And to clarify, it appears that for example, you want AT MOST, 3 entries per class (person name per sample data).  If one class has only a single entry, get it.  However, if someone else has 8 classes you want only the first 3 based on some pre-determined priority ordering, such as top 3 scores.

In your case, the OVER is partitioned by the "class", and the order by will be the score DESC (descending).  So having the view give you this extra computed column (per class), you can then filter `WHERE finalColumnNameYouAssign <= 3`

Comment: I was trying to make my example simple. but there is a LOT more data. I will edit my question and add SQL import data so it can be used in testing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered similar question yesterday. See [How to limit SQL query with JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043925/how-to-limit-sql-query-with-join/73044487#73044487)

Here's my solution based on 2 linked tables, `users` and `history` for each `user`. There is also another solution there depending on your MySQL version.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `users` AS u
    LEFT JOIN `history` AS h ON u.id = h.user_id 
    
WHERE 
    
FIND_IN_SET(h.id, (SELECT `list` FROM 
(SELECT user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) AS `list` FROM 
(SELECT h.user_id, h.id
FROM 
    `users` AS u
    LEFT JOIN `history` AS h ON u.id = h.user_id
) AS `a`
GROUP BY user_id
) AS `b`
WHERE b.user_id = u.id  
    
    ) )
```