# How to limit SQL query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

I have two tables, in one table is news in another is images linked with id from news

`news`

| id | title | main_image | services |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New title | path_to_image_main_image | Photo |
| 2 | New title 2 | path_to_image_main_image | Photo |

`images`

| id | file_name | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IMG_8045.jpg | 1 |
| 2 | IMG_8046.jpg | 1 |
| 3 | IMG_8047.jpg | 2 |
| 4 | IMG_8048.jpg | 2 |
| 5 | IMG_8049.jpg | 2 |

`new_id` is id from `news` table

My SQL query is
`SELECT n.id, n.title, n.main_image, n.services, i.file_name FROM news AS n INNER JOIN images AS i ON n.id = i.new_id`
I need to limit this query with 2 images from `images` table per `id` from `news` table

Comment: Please add your MySQL version

Comment: MySQL version 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By MySQL version 10.5 I assume you mean MariaDB version 10.5... seeing as MySQL is only on version 8.0 at the moment ;)

I'm not too familiar with the syntax differences between MySQL and MariaDB, but here's a query that works in MySQL 8.0... which technically should work for you in MariaDB 10.5 (seeing as they've had window functions since 10.2 - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/)

```
SELECT
    r.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    n.id,
    n.title,
    n.main_image,
    n.services,
    i.file_name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.new_id ORDER BY i.id) AS row_num
    FROM news n
    INNER JOIN images i ON i.new_id = n.id
) r
WHERE r.row_num <= 2;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, this is working. Just `ON i.news_id` need to be `ON i.new_id` without s on the end. Thank you. Actually, this does not solve my problem, but it works for what I want to try.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that supports MySQL 5.6. It is such a mess but it works. I hope performance is not an issue.

Basically it runs the JOIN first time, grouping by id of first table concatenating the ids of second table as a comma separated list.  Then do the original join limiting to the list of ids.

Substitute `users` with `news` and `history` with `images` to name your tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `users` AS u
    LEFT JOIN `history` AS h ON u.id = h.user_id 
    
WHERE 
    
FIND_IN_SET(h.id, (SELECT `list` FROM 
(SELECT user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) AS `list` FROM 
(SELECT h.user_id, h.id
FROM 
    `users` AS u
    LEFT JOIN `history` AS h ON u.id = h.user_id
) AS `a`
GROUP BY user_id
) AS `b`
WHERE b.user_id = u.id  
    
    ) )
```